# chrome.tabs.sendMessage won't work in async then function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await

## in the background script

```
function new_url_listener(tabId, info, tab) {

    if(info.url){
        get_template(info.url).then(function(template){
            console.log(template);
            if (template){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {test:"test"}, function(response) {    
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }        
        })
    }
}



chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(new_url_listener);
```

## in content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(sender.tab ?
                  "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                  "from the extension");
      if (request.greeting == "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

it sends a message when the chrome.tabs.sendMessage is not contained within the get_template.then() call, but I need to be able to send the template variable to the content script

why won't it send within the then call?

get_template makes a call to an api and gets json back as the template variable

Comment: 1. Use debugger to set breakpoints and see what happens 2. Try `tabId` instead of `tab.id`

Comment: so I did that, and I found that the send message doesn't work within the if statement, without it it works. what could that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": [
            "contentscript.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start"

    }
],
```

I had to add "run_at": "document_start" and now it works